# How to open localhost server on computer

Tags: asp.net, localhost

I am making project on a asp.net(c#). I have completed  my project and also i have make a software disc of my project. But when i am trying to access localhost.it show authentication required dialog box.which contain username and password.But i have not set any username and password. How can i overcome from this problem.

Answer (score 3):

[This](http://forums.asp.net/t/1183560.aspx/1?localhost%20kept%20on%20asking%20me%20for%20password) might help. Especially the solution by ***nramsey34***

> In IIS, you can right click on either
>   the Website, or any virtual directory
>   under a website and bring up the
>   properties page.  Under the 'Directory
>   Security' tab, click the Edit button
>   under 'Anonymous Access and
>   Authentication Control'.  This will
>   bring up a window where you can
>   configure the authentication method
>   for your website.  To stop it from
>   asking for a password, make sure that
>   Anonymous Access is selected.  The
>   username should look like this -
>   IUSR_YOURPCNAME, and you should let
>   IIS control the password. You should
>   still be able to leave Windows
>   Authentication selected as well, but
>   to be certain it will not ask for a
>   password you can also uncheck that
>   box.

or [this](http://bytes.com/topic/asp-classic/answers/590809-enter-username-password-http-localhost) one, the solution by ***boyban***

> The Login Popup is due to a setting in
>   your IE Browser.  In your IE Browser:
>
> 1. Go to the Top menu "Tools" -> "Internet Options".
> 2. Then choose the "Advanced" Tab.
> 3. Then Scroll all the way down and "Uncheck" the Checkbox corresponding
>      to "Enable Integrated Windows
>      Authentication".
> 4. Then Click the button that says "Apply" and then "OK".
> 5. Close the browser and in a new browser try http://localhost.